# Is there any way to switch windows in VScode via keyboard shortcut when the focus is on the terminal?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

I would like to switch between windows (vscode) regardless if the focus is on the editor or on (any) terminal. I tried the key binding below in the json file without any luck. Also, dropping the `"when"` clause or only using terminalFocus doesn't work. It seems I can only switch windows if the focus is on the editor. Would be grateful for any suggestions.

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+w",
    "command": "workbench.action.switchWindow",
    "when": "terminalFocus || editorTextFocus"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my testing I see two options:

(1) It appears that any other keybinding except <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> works as expected; or

(2) add your command `workbench.action.switchWindow` to the `Terminal > Integrated: Commands to Skip Shell` list in your settings if you want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> as your keybinding.

Comment: Thanks! Another key binding would not work (1) but adding the command to the skip shell list (2) did the trick.

Comment: Great, don't forget to accept the answer if it was correct and helpful.   Thank you.